# supabase auth error AuthApiError: "Database error finding user from email link"

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase

I have a nextjs 14/supabase app (using app router and ssr). When a new user signs up via email and clicks the accept invite link, they get an error "*Database error finding user from email link*".

I've configurated the email link to be as follows:

`{{ .SiteURL }}/auth/confirm?token_hash={{.TokenHash}}&type=email&next={{.SiteURL}}/projects"`

My auth/confirm/route.ts file is as follows:

```
import { EmailOtpType } from "@supabase/supabase-js"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url)
  const token_hash = searchParams.get("token_hash")
  const next = searchParams.get("next")
  const type = searchParams.get("type")
  const cookieStore = cookies()

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name) {
          return cookieStore.get(name)?.value
        },
        set(name, value, options) {
          cookieStore.set({ name, value, ...options })
        },
        remove(name, options) {
          cookieStore.set({ name, value: "", ...options })
        },
      },
    },
  )

  if (token_hash && type) {
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.verifyOtp({
      type: assertOtpType(type),
      token_hash,
    })
    console.log({ error })
    if (!error) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(next!)
    }
  }
  return NextResponse.redirect(process.env.SITE_URL + "/error")
}

function assertOtpType(type: string): EmailOtpType {
  if (type !== "email") {
    throw new Error("Invalid OTP type")
  }
  return type
}
```

I have my `auth.users` table and my `public.users` table. There is a trigger and a function to insert the new user in the `public.users` table. This seems to work when the user signs up. It's just when the confirm with the email link that things break.

When the user signs up, I do notice a cookie is created `sb-vfhoyptcwlciarlfXXXX-auth-token-code-verifier` with value `%22b37534612078b7ddc7450ebee93be7ad6da263e945c18f6418d8f45568196013adbd864a392f197c20f9108ac3046cbee1030dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` (changed some values to X's in case this is not safe to post).

Here is the code for when the user signs up:

```
import { createClientServer } from "@/supabase/server"

export const signUp = async (formData: FormData, captchaToken: string) => {
  const email = formData.get("email") as string
  const password = formData.get("password") as string
  const supabase = createClientServer()
  const origin = process.env.SITE_URL

  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email,
    password,
    options: {
      emailRedirectTo: `${origin}/projects`,
      captchaToken: captchaToken,
    },
  })

  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } else {
    console.log("Check your email for the confirmation link.")
  }
}
```

Any ideas on this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a malformatted confirmation link in your auth email template.

Just replace `{{ .SiteURL }}/auth/confirm?token_hash={{.TokenHash}}&type=email&next={{.SiteURL}}/projects` with `{{ .ConfirmationURL }}` in your email template, and it should work just fine.